# StackOverflowError in Eclipse while running Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, memory, stack-overflow

Lately i ran into some memory issues which i have been trying to solve the paste few days, but unfortunately without any luck!

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8 / 8GB RAM (Should not be any allocation problems!)

Eclipse version is Helios.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

My Java exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

And my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1G
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:PermSize=1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

I have also tried to add "-Xmx1536m" to my VM arguments in Eclipse, but without any luck at all!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the stacktrace of the error. That would give an idea about the problematic methods. Do you use any recursions in your code? If so watchout your base cases.

Comment: That's a typical problem for this site! ;-)

Comment: I will debug once again and pay attention to (perhaps) missing base cases in the code.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflowError is a common error when you have an infinite recursive call such as :

```
void method(int a) {
    method(a);
}
```

this kind of calls will lead to the StackOverflowError.

So you should check in your code if you have this type of infinite recursive calls or maybe an endless loop.

Comment: I will step through my code once again. It just seems like an odd coincidence that my code compiles on my secondary machine without any exceptions. And i am indeed working with recursion.

Comment: @JavaCake Post your code and we can help you identify the endless recursive call maybe.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 
Right click on project follow below steps:

- Run
- Run Configurations
- click on JRE tab
- In VM arguments section write below parameters
  -Xss**2g**

By default stack memory size is 512 KB. We can increase as per our need.

- Click on apply and run project..

If in case any query, revert comment in comment sections.